# How to change the alpha of Popup header in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to make the header of a pop-up less transparent than the default one. Please see below image:

[image]

I can read the text written beneath it. Is there a way i can change the Alpha of it. I tried changing the header color using following:

```
titleWin.setStyle("headerColors",  [blue, blue]);
```

But it is still showing the header as transparent. Please help!!

Comment: then why even bother commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick :

```
titleWin.setStyle("borderAlpha","1.0");
```